# How to parse a string to a float compatible with Numba `njit()`?

Tags: python, string, parsing, numba

I have some Numba accelerated code in NoPython mode using `numbaa.njit()`.
At some point I need to parse a `str` (or `bytes`) to get a `float`.

In pure Python, the way I would go about it is with `float()`, but that does not work:

```py
import numba as nb


@nb.njit
def str2float(text):
    return float(text)


str2float("1.2")
```

> TypingError: Failed in nopython mode pipeline (step: nopython frontend)
> No implementation of function Function(<class 'float'>) found for signature:
> `>>> float(unicode_type)`

while I would like it to produce a `float` with value `1.2`.

---

The following questions are somewhat related:

- [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/69601762/5218354) discusses parsing to `int` (`str`/`bytes`-to-`int`)
- [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58552951/convert-float-to-string-numba-python-numpy-array) discusses the opposite, i.e. the conversion of a `float`-to-`str` conversion

Comment: Does this answer your question? [convert float to string numba python numpy array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58552951/convert-float-to-string-numba-python-numpy-array) Oh shoot, guess not, you wrote an answer there yesterday. This still appears to be unsupported by numba, though...

Comment: @DominikStańczak that is the other way around

Comment: Oh. Darn, yeah, you're right. My bad! Sorry, not enough tea in the morning!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While this is not yet supported (as of July 2022), you can implement something manually.

Below are two versions, one for `str` and one for `bytes`.

In the process of solving the task I use a `str`/`bytes`-to-`int` which is used to parse `str` that include the exponential notation e.g. `1.0e-02` and -- potentially -- a `trim()` function to pre-process inputs surrounded by [whitespaces](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Whitespace_character) (["C" whitespaces](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1548.pdf): `" "`, `"\n"`, `"\r"`, `"\t"`, `"\v"`).

Both are presented [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73225712/5218354) and only used below.

---

## From `str`

```py
import math
import numba as nb


@nb.njit
def str2float_helper(text):
    sep = ord(".")
    c_min = ord("0")
    c_max = ord("9")

    n = len(text)
    valid = n > 0
    # determine sign
    start = n - 1
    stop = -1
    sign = 1
    if valid:
        first = ord(text[0])
        if first == ord("+"):
            stop = 0
        elif first == ord("-"):
            sign = -1
            stop = 0
    # parse rest
    sep_pos = 0
    number = 0
    j = 0
    for i in range(start, stop, -1):
        c = ord(text[i])
        if c_min <= c <= c_max:
            number += (c - c_min) * 10 ** j
            j += 1
        elif c == sep and sep_pos == 0:
            sep_pos = j
        else:
            valid = False
            break
    return sign * number, sep_pos, valid


@nb.njit
def str2float(text):
    if text == "nan" or text == "NAN" or text == "NaN":
        return math.nan
    exp_chars = b"eE"
    exp_pos = -1
    for exp_char in exp_chars:
        for i, c in enumerate(text[::-1]):
            c = ord(c)
            if c == exp_char:
                exp_pos = i
                break
        if exp_pos > -1:
            break
    if exp_pos > 0:
        exp_number = str2int(text[-exp_pos:])
        if exp_number is None:
            exp_number = 0
        number, sep_pos, valid = str2float_helper(text[:-exp_pos-1])
        result = number / 10.0 ** (sep_pos - exp_number) if valid else None
    else:
        number, sep_pos, valid = str2float_helper(text)
        result = number / 10.0 ** sep_pos if valid else None
    return result
```

This should work similarly to `float_()` (defined below) which is a helper function that returns `None` instead of raising in case of parsing failure:

```py
def float_(x):
    try:
        return float(x)
    except ValueError:
        return None


def is_close(x, y):
    if x and not y or not x and y:
        return False
    else:
        return x == y or math.isclose(x, y) or math.isnan(x) and math.isnan(y)


numbers = (
    "", "NaN", "10", "32.1", "4123.43214e+05", "4123.43214E+05", "4123.43214e-05",
    "-31", "-12.3", "-4123.43214e+05", "-4123.43214E+05", "-4123.43214e-05",
    " 1321.432 \t ", "1+2", "1-2", "1e", "e1",
)
k = 24
for number in numbers:
    print(f"{number!r:{k}}  {float_(number)!s:{k}}  {str2float(number)!s:{k}}  {is_close(float_(number), str2float(number))}")
# ''                        None                      None                      True
# 'NaN'                     nan                       nan                       True
# '10'                      10.0                      10.0                      True
# '32.1'                    32.1                      32.1                      True
# '4123.43214e+05'          412343214.0               412343214.0               True
# '4123.43214E+05'          412343214.0               412343214.0               True
# '4123.43214e-05'          0.0412343214              0.0412343214              True
# '-31'                     -31.0                     -31.0                     True
# '-12.3'                   -12.3                     -12.3                     True
# '-4123.43214e+05'         -412343214.0              -412343214.0              True
# '-4123.43214E+05'         -412343214.0              -412343214.0              True
# '-4123.43214e-05'         -0.0412343214             -0.0412343214             True
# ' 1321.432 \t '           1321.432                  None                      False
# '1+2'                     None                      None                      True
# '1-2'                     None                      None                      True
# '1e'                      None                      None                      True
# 'e1'                      None                      None                      True
# '1.1e-200'                1.1e-200                  1.0999999999999995e-200   True
# '1.1e+200'                1.1e+200                  1.1000000000000005e+200   True
```

(except for the trimming whitespaces part which can be added if needed).

Timewise, this is some 12x slower than pure Python:

```py
%timeit -n 32 -r 32 [str2float(number) for number in numbers]
# 32 loops, best of 32: 80.3 µs per loop
%timeit -n 32 -r 32 [float_(number) for number in numbers]
# 32 loops, best of 32: 6.55 µs per loop
```

and hence only useful if this is needed as part of a more complex `njit()`-ed code.

---

## From `bytes`

This is essentially a rewrite of the above to work with `bytes` (which typically only require skipping some `ord()`, because iterating `bytes` provides the integer representation directly) or defining a `==` operator because that is not available for `bytes`.

```py
@nb.njit
def bytes2float_helper(text):
    sep = ord(".")
    c_min = ord("0")
    c_max = ord("9")

    n = len(text)
    valid = n > 0
    # determine sign
    start = n - 1
    stop = -1
    sign = 1
    if valid:
        first = text[0]
        if first == ord("+"):
            stop = 0
        elif first == ord("-"):
            sign = -1
            stop = 0
    # parse rest
    sep_pos = 0
    number = 0
    j = 0
    for i in range(start, stop, -1):
        c = text[i]
        if c_min <= c <= c_max:
            number += (c - c_min) * 10 ** j
            j += 1
        elif c == sep and sep_pos == 0:
            sep_pos = j
        else:
            valid = False
            break
    return sign * number, sep_pos, valid


@nb.njit
def eqb(text_a, text_b):
    len_a = len(text_a)
    len_b = len(text_b)
    if len_a == len_b:
        for i in range(len_a):
            if text_a[i] != text_b[i]:
                return False
        return True
    else:
        return False


@nb.njit
def bytes2float(text):
    if eqb(text, b"nan") or eqb(text, b"NAN") or eqb(text, b"NaN"):
        return math.nan
    exp_chars = b"eE"
    exp_pos = -1
    for exp_char in exp_chars:
        for i, c in enumerate(text[::-1]):
            if c == exp_char:
                exp_pos = i
                break
        if exp_pos > -1:
            break
    if exp_pos > 0:
        exp_number = bytes2int(text[-exp_pos:])
        if exp_number is None:
            exp_number = 0
        number, sep_pos, valid = bytes2float_helper(text[:-exp_pos-1])
        result = number / 10.0 ** (sep_pos - exp_number) if valid else None
    else:
        number, sep_pos, valid = bytes2float_helper(text)
        result = number / 10.0 ** sep_pos if valid else None
    return result
```

The interesting bit it of this is that this has comparable speed (albeit marginally slower by some 15%) as the pure Python counterpart:

```py
numbers = (
    b"", b"NaN", b"10", b"32.1", b"4123.43214e+05", b"4123.43214E+05", b"4123.43214e-05",
    b"-31", b"-12.3", b"-4123.43214e+05", b"-4123.43214E+05", b"-4123.43214e-05",
    b" 1321.432   ", b"1+2", b"1-2", b"1e", b"e1", b"1.1e-200", b"1.1e+200",
)
k = 24
for number in numbers:
    print(f"{number!s:{k}}  {float_(number)!s:{k}}  {bytes2float(number)!s:{k}}  {is_close(float_(number), bytes2float(number))}")
# b''                       None                      None                      True
# b'NaN'                    nan                       nan                       True
# b'10'                     10.0                      10.0                      True
# b'32.1'                   32.1                      32.1                      True
# b'4123.43214e+05'         412343214.0               412343214.0               True
# b'4123.43214E+05'         412343214.0               412343214.0               True
# b'4123.43214e-05'         0.0412343214              0.0412343214              True
# b'-31'                    -31.0                     -31.0                     True
# b'-12.3'                  -12.3                     -12.3                     True
# b'-4123.43214e+05'        -412343214.0              -412343214.0              True
# b'-4123.43214E+05'        -412343214.0              -412343214.0              True
# b'-4123.43214e-05'        -0.0412343214             -0.0412343214             True
# b' 1321.432   '           1321.432                  None                      False
# b'1+2'                    None                      None                      True
# b'1-2'                    None                      None                      True
# b'1e'                     None                      None                      True
# b'e1'                     None                      None                      True
# b'1.1e-200'               1.1e-200                  1.0999999999999995e-200   True
# b'1.1e+200'               1.1e+200                  1.1000000000000005e+200   True


%timeit -n 32 -r 32 [bytes2float(number) for number in numbers]
# 32 loops, best of 32: 8.84 µs per loop
%timeit -n 32 -r 32 [float_(number) for number in numbers]
# 32 loops, best of 32: 7.66 µs per loop
```

Comment: The current string interface of Numba is very slow and AFAIK there is no way to get avoid this. It is less true for bytearrays but there are still not great in term of performance. Such function deserve to be provided in Numba by default. Using a lower-level interface might improve performance. Note that using the objmode should help to get the same performance than CPython but objmode sections cannot be used in some cases like parallel code for example (because of GIL-related issues).